# UITableView's numberOfSections not being called when reloadData is executed asynchronously

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous

So I have a `UITableView` hooked up with the `UIViewController` (including the `delegate` and `datasource`).

`@IBOutlet weak var chatTableView: UITableView!`

When I try to call `chatTableView.reloadData()` after fetching some data from a webservice **asynchronously**, it will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but it won't call neither `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection`. When I try to call it from a `@IBAction` (not asynchronously) both methods are executed just fine.

I've tried calling `reloadData()` using `DispatchQueue.main.async` and `OperationQueue.main.addOperation` but without success.

```
ChatRepository.list {
    log, error in
    // bunch of code
    self.log = log
    self.isInputHidden = true
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // This won't call numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSections
        self.chatTableView.reloadData()
    }   
}

@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any?) {
    // This will call the complete flow of methods
    chatTableView.reloadData()
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let sections = log.count + (isInputHidden ? 1 : 2)
    return sections
}
```

Any thoughts on why both methods are not being called?

Comment: How are you dictating the number of sections and rows?  Are you updating the array associated with these values prior to reloading the view?

Comment: Actually yes, I forgot to mention it. Will update the question.

Comment: @rMickeyD done.

Comment: How is this compiling if your `numberOfSections(in:)` func is not marked with `override`?

Comment: @MichaelFourre if this class simply adheres to `UITableViewDataSource`, not a subclass of `UITableViewController`, there's no need for `override`.

Comment: @DanielFariaSampaio are you sure `self.chatTableView.reloadData()` is getting called (at all) inside the `main.async` block?

Comment: Good point @GrahamPerks thanks for the input

Comment: Yes @GrahamPerks it is, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being executed.

Comment: any solution ???